# Check if the user give value to argument with default value

Tags: r, function

I have a function `f(x)` where the default value of `x` is 2. The function returns the square.

```
f <- function(x = 2){
      return(x^2)
     }
```

I want to check in the function if the user gives value to `x`. Even if the value given is 2, I want to know.

Perhaps this is the equivalent code of what I want.

```
 f <- function(x){
       if(!missing(x)) print("User did not give value to x")
       if(missing(x)) x <- 2
     return(x^2)
    }
```

I want to do something similar by setting the default value of x to 2 (not `NULL` also). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `match.call`. In this case we could do

```
f <- function(x = 2) {
  if(is.null(match.call()$x))
    print("Nothing")
  x^2
}

f()
# [1] "Nothing"
# [1] 4

f(2)
# [1] 4

f(x = 2)
# [1] 4
```